# How can I use Boost.Bind on compound types?

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-lambda

I have `std::map<int, std::pair<short, float> >`, and I need to find the minimal `short` in this map. How can I use `boost::bind` with `std::min_element()` for this?

`boost::lambda`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `map` iterator will give you a `pair` where `first` is the `int` key and `second` is the map's `pair` value, so if you had an iterator `it`, you'd want the minimum of all the `it->second.first` values. The `min_element` function expects a comparison function for its third argument, so you need to build a comparison function that projects `second.first` of its two arguments.

We'll start with some typedefs to make the code more readable:

```
typedef std::pair<short, float> val_type;
typedef std::map<int, val_type> map_type;
map_type m;
```

We're going to use Boost.Lambda for its overloaded operators, allowing us to use `operator<`. Boost.Bind can bind member variables as well as member functions, so we'll take advantage of that, too.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
using boost::bind;

// Comparison is (_1.second.first < _2.second.first)
std::cout <<
  std::min_element(m.begin(), m.end(),
    bind(&val_type::first, bind(&map_type::iterator::value_type::second, _1))
    <
    bind(&val_type::first, bind(&map_type::iterator::value_type::second, _2))
  )->second.first;
```

That will also work with `boost::lambda::bind`.

Answer (score 5):

```
min_element(map.begin(), map.end(),
            compose2(less<short>(),
                     compose1(select1st<pair<short, float> >(),
                              select2nd<map<int, pair<short, float>
                                           >::value_type>()),
                     compose1(select1st<pair<short, float> >(),
                              select2nd<map<int, pair<short, float>
                                           >::value_type>()))
           ).second.first;
```

(Of course, somebody's going to complain that this is an abuse of STL and that these are extensions not in the C++ standard…)

Comment: Well, I would complain about nonstandard extensions, but as far as "STL abuse" goes I think it's perfectly fine :) +1. Luckily the nonstandard bits are easy to write yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` cannot do this by itself, because `first` and `second` are exposed as fields, not methods (so you can't get away with something like `mem_fun`).

You could do this using your own functor of course though:

```
template <typename F, typename S>
struct select_first : std::binary_function<std::pair<F, S>&, F&>
{
    F& operator()(std::pair<F, S>& toConvert)
    {
        return toConvert.first;
    }
};
```

Comment: Also known as `select1st` in some C++ libraries.

Comment: @ephemient: True -- wasn't aware that it was already included with SGI's STL. In that case I would recommend leaving the name this way because SGI's supports any pair-like interface, while this one only works with std::pair.